# How long after baking do American chewy cookies get their normal texture?

Tags: cookies, texture, american-cuisine

I just baked my first ever batch of American-style cookies (chewy chocolate chip cookies). I used the correct ingredients, including actual wet brown sugar, except for the chocolate - I had no chocolate chips, so I used chopped milk chocolate (I know, I know...).

I have experienced this type of cookies as a light, but not soft baked good. When I have had them, they have been slightly airy, but more tough than brittle. I suppose that this is the desired texture, as they are called "chewy".

I took my first batch out of the oven, and it seems that I reached too deep with the glove and touched a cookie. It was squished. All the cookies turned out to be puffy and prone to deflating. Also, they have a cracked surface, unlike the pictures in the [recipe illustrations](http://smittenkitchen.com/2009/03/crispy-chewy-chocolate-chip-cookies/).

Is this normal? Will they get their expected texture later? How much will I have to wait for them to get the desired texture? Or did I make a mistake?

I didn't cool the dough, although I have read often that cookie dough should be kept cold. The reason is that this recipe directed me to melt the butter, and didn't include cooling steps, so I assumed that a warm dough is normal for the recipe.

[image: squished cookie]

Comment: Hm. The difference between your cookies and the ones from the illustration seems to be the same as the difference between my mother-in-law's cookies (in the USA) and my cookies (not in the USA). But I always use oil + water + extra bit of flour rather than her mix of oil and margarine.

Comment: Mmm! Those look perfect!  Don't let them cool too much before eating at least one, because they may be squishy, but they're good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cookies will set (take on their final texture) about by 20 - 30 minutes out of the oven.  Coming directly out of the oven, cookies will absolutely be soft and squishable; which is why you should wait a few minutes before moving them off the baking sheet and onto a cooling rack (you can cheat this time if your cookies are all on a sheet of parchment paper, and you move the parchment paper as a whole).

Answer (score 5):

Those look absolutely perfect and it is normal for them to be very soft straight out of the oven. They will get chewy as they cool and dry out a little.